# VRP example in the docs gives different output when I run it

Tags: python, or-tools

On https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp, it says:

> The complete programs are shown in the next section. When you run the programs, they display the following output:
>
> Route for vehicle 0:
> 0 -> 8 -> 6 -> 2 -> 5 -> 0
> Distance of route: 1552m
>
> Route for vehicle 1:  0 -> 7 -> 1 -> 4 -> 3 -> 0 Distance of route:
> 1552m
>
> Route for vehicle 2:  0 -> 9 -> 10 -> 16 -> 14 -> 0 Distance of route:
> 1552m
>
> Route for vehicle 3:  0 -> 12 -> 11 -> 15 -> 13 -> 0 Distance of
> route: 1552m
>
> Total distance of all routes: 6208m

However, when I run the example given on that page:

```
"""Simple Vehicles Routing Problem (VRP).

   This is a sample using the routing library python wrapper to solve a VRP
   problem.
   A description of the problem can be found here:
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem.

   Distances are in meters.
"""

from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp


def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['distance_matrix'] = [
        [
            0, 548, 776, 696, 582, 274, 502, 194, 308, 194, 536, 502, 388, 354,
            468, 776, 662
        ],
        [
            548, 0, 684, 308, 194, 502, 730, 354, 696, 742, 1084, 594, 480, 674,
            1016, 868, 1210
        ],
        [
            776, 684, 0, 992, 878, 502, 274, 810, 468, 742, 400, 1278, 1164,
            1130, 788, 1552, 754
        ],
        [
            696, 308, 992, 0, 114, 650, 878, 502, 844, 890, 1232, 514, 628, 822,
            1164, 560, 1358
        ],
        [
            582, 194, 878, 114, 0, 536, 764, 388, 730, 776, 1118, 400, 514, 708,
            1050, 674, 1244
        ],
        [
            274, 502, 502, 650, 536, 0, 228, 308, 194, 240, 582, 776, 662, 628,
            514, 1050, 708
        ],
        [
            502, 730, 274, 878, 764, 228, 0, 536, 194, 468, 354, 1004, 890, 856,
            514, 1278, 480
        ],
        [
            194, 354, 810, 502, 388, 308, 536, 0, 342, 388, 730, 468, 354, 320,
            662, 742, 856
        ],
        [
            308, 696, 468, 844, 730, 194, 194, 342, 0, 274, 388, 810, 696, 662,
            320, 1084, 514
        ],
        [
            194, 742, 742, 890, 776, 240, 468, 388, 274, 0, 342, 536, 422, 388,
            274, 810, 468
        ],
        [
            536, 1084, 400, 1232, 1118, 582, 354, 730, 388, 342, 0, 878, 764,
            730, 388, 1152, 354
        ],
        [
            502, 594, 1278, 514, 400, 776, 1004, 468, 810, 536, 878, 0, 114,
            308, 650, 274, 844
        ],
        [
            388, 480, 1164, 628, 514, 662, 890, 354, 696, 422, 764, 114, 0, 194,
            536, 388, 730
        ],
        [
            354, 674, 1130, 822, 708, 628, 856, 320, 662, 388, 730, 308, 194, 0,
            342, 422, 536
        ],
        [
            468, 1016, 788, 1164, 1050, 514, 514, 662, 320, 274, 388, 650, 536,
            342, 0, 764, 194
        ],
        [
            776, 868, 1552, 560, 674, 1050, 1278, 742, 1084, 810, 1152, 274,
            388, 422, 764, 0, 798
        ],
        [
            662, 1210, 754, 1358, 1244, 708, 480, 856, 514, 468, 354, 844, 730,
            536, 194, 798, 0
        ],
    ]
    data['num_vehicles'] = 4
    data['depot'] = 0
    return data


def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    print(f'Objective: {solution.ObjectiveValue()}')
    max_route_distance = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        route_distance = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            plan_output += ' {} -> '.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
            previous_index = index
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
                previous_index, index, vehicle_id)
        plan_output += '{}\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        plan_output += 'Distance of the route: {}m\n'.format(route_distance)
        print(plan_output)
        max_route_distance = max(route_distance, max_route_distance)
    print('Maximum of the route distances: {}m'.format(max_route_distance))



def main():
    """Entry point of the program."""
    # Instantiate the data problem.
    data = create_data_model()

    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)


    # Create and register a transit callback.
    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    # Add Distance constraint.
    dimension_name = 'Distance'
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        0,  # no slack
        3000,  # vehicle maximum travel distance
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        dimension_name)
    distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
    distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)

    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    # Print solution on console.
    if solution:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)
    else:
        print('No solution found !')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get the following output:

> Objective: 177500
> Route for vehicle 0:  0 ->  9 ->  10 ->  2 ->  6 ->
> 5 -> 0 Distance of the route: 1712m
>
> Route for vehicle 1:  0 ->  16 ->  14 ->  8 -> 0 Distance of the
> route: 1484m
>
> Route for vehicle 2:  0 ->  7 ->  1 ->  4 ->  3 -> 0 Distance of the
> route: 1552m
>
> Route for vehicle 3:  0 ->  13 ->  15 ->  11 ->  12 -> 0 Distance of
> the route: 1552m
>
> Maximum of the route distances: 1712m

I'm running the latest version of the python ortools library (9.5) with Python 3.11.

#### So

Are the docs wrong?

Or is the code in the latest release bugged (the solution it gives is worse than the docs, so it may be a regression)?

Or is there something messed up with my local environment that is causing the difference? Is it happening for other people too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are simple examples with just a greedy descent.
The result is very dependent on how we chain local search operators. This changed in a recent release but the docs were not updated.

If you add any meta-heuristic, you will easily get the best solution.

See discussion in the [issue #3570](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/3570)

Comment: Many thanks. This explains how to change the code to get the solution that matches the docs. And it confirms it's not something messed up with my environment as others have found the same thing. However, it still isn't clear if the example greedy algorithm is now bugged, or whether it was intentionally changed and the docs are stale. One way or another though, something isn't right, as the example code doesn't produce what the docs state it should.

Comment: docs are stale :-)